# Protractor, do I have to use then() after protractor calls?

Tags: promise, protractor, chaining, method-chaining

Is it ok to write:

```
getFieldX().clear().sendKeys('abc');
```

or should I write:

```
getFieldX().clear().then( () => sendKeys('abc));
```

I'm totally confused about the Promise handling in protractor. `clear()` returns a promise, so I should use `.then()` afterwards, shouldn't I?

But I found examples with .then and some without.
Protractor itself has an example without `.then()`:
https://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow

Does Protractor has its own mechanism and resolves one after the other promise so there is no need for using `.then()` after a protractor call that returns a Promise?

And is the control flow of protractor only active in a spec?
When using `.sendKeys()` in a normal function I have to use `.sendKeys().then(...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on if you are using `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` or not. As this is (has?) becoming deprecated, I would not use it. It should be set to false by default, but if you want to be sure you can add `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER = false;` to your conf file. The way that protractor has been moving is to use **async/await**, so your sendKeys function would look like:

```
let field = element(by.css('CSS.Selector'));
await field.clear();
await field.sendKeys('abc');
```

Because these are async functions, you will need to define your function properly, so a basic spec would look like:

```
describe('Demonstrating async/await',function(){
  it('Should send some keys', async function(){
    let field = element(by.css('CSS.Selector'));
    await field.clear();
    await field.sendKeys('abc');
  });
});
```

The important difference there is that a function needs to be defined as `async function()`. As far as reading the code goes, `await` simply can be read as "Wait until promise resolved to move on". It does get a bit tedious and you feel like you write `await` before every line of code (you basically do), but I find it significantly better than `.then()` trees.

Comment: We have a mix of tests and plan to migrate to async. So when using SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER = true I don't have to use .then() after protractor functions like clear() and sendKeys(), correct?

Comment: When using asnyc/await you should have `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER = false`

Comment: @GarfieldKlon but yes, when using async, you do not need to use .then()